# getter setter scope in java

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, getter-setter

I have a class which has the following code:

```
public class Crawler {

    String title;

    public void setTitle(String text) {
        title=text;
        //System.out.println(title);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        // System.out.println(title);
        return title;
    }

    public void crawler() {
        Document doc;
        doc = connect("http://www.xyz.com//asd.html").timeout(0).get();
        title=doc.title();
        setTitle(title);
        System.out.println("Title : " + title);
    }
}
```

another class:

```
public class Results {

    public void output() {
        Crawler cw=new Crawler();
        System.out.println(cw.getTitle());
    }
}
```

The thing is that, the SOP in the results class is printing `null`

The commented SOP in `setTitle()` is printing the text needed but the SOP in `getTitle()` is still saying `null`.

Is there any scope issues here? I'm not getting it. Doesn't the global title variable change when I call the `setTitle()` method?

Im sorry I forgot to mention this, I have a class below which calls the methods inthe below manner:

EDIT 1:

```
public class OA {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Crawler cw=new Crawler();
        //LoadIntoDB ld= new LoadIntoDB();
        Results op=new Results();

        cw.crawler();
        //ld.load();
        op.output();
    }
}
```

When i run the OA class, the crawler and results class's methods are called. Im getting null still.

Comment: "`Document doc; title=doc.title();`" Can this compile? `doc` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 5):

> The thing is that, the SOP in the results class is printing null

Yes, it would. You're never calling the `crawler` method, which is the only thing to call `setTitle`. Perhaps you meant it to be a constructor? If so, you need to change the declaration from this:

```
public void crawler() {
```

To this:

```
public Crawler() {
```

Comment: I've edited my question, there is a class OA which calls the methods.

Comment: @user2500875: There's not enough information for us to work out what's going on. You've effectively changed the question completely. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have just instantiated the `Crawler` class. It has an instance variable `String title;`. Instance reference variables will be defaulted to `null` if not assigned specifically . You need to call `setTitle()` to set the `title` or else the `getTitle()` is bound to return `null`.

Important thing here is `crawler()` is not the constructor for `Crawler` class. **Java is case-sensitive .**

**After the question was edited:**

In its current implementation , `cw.crawler()` should throw **NPE** . Just look at the code of `crawler()`:

```
public void crawler() {
    Document doc;
    title=doc.title(); // null pointer here , doc was never instantiated
    setTitle(title);
    System.out.println("Title : " + title);
}
```

**After the question was re-edited:**

In the `public static void main()` method , you are creating an instance of `Crawler` and calling its `crawler()` method to set its `title`.

```
Crawler cw=new Crawler();
```

But when you call `output()` method , you are creating a different object of `Crawler` , it is a new object for which the `title` is `null` :

```
public void output() {
    Crawler cw=new Crawler(); // new object
    System.out.println(cw.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question, there is a class OA which calls the methods.

Comment: I edited again, that line got deleted by mistake. When i try to print the value of title in the getter method, its still giving me null. Why is that? I thought that if I set the value of title in the setter, then when i pritn it in the getter it shud pprint the value right?

Comment: Oh yea! TY for that but even if i extend it still null.Y is it that if i try to print the value of "title" in the getter method itself im getting null? but in the setter method its gives me the correct o/p

Comment: It worked if i gave it as static String in the Crawler class. How?

Comment: `static` variables are shared by all instances of a class.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `title` is `null` so `getTitle` returns `null`.
You created a new object of `Crawler` in another class and your existing code does not set the `title`.

If you want a title to be set automatically then you need to keep that code in constructor

```
public Crawler() {
    //some code to get your document
    title=doc.title();
    setTitle(title);
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question, there is a class OA which calls the methods.

Answer (score 1):

1st Change `public void crawler()` to 
    `public Crawler()` 
2nd thing

```
public void crawler() {
    Document doc;
    title=doc.title();
    setTitle(title);
    System.out.println("Title : " + title);
}
```

assign doc with some value otherwise you will get NullPointerException

Comment: I've edited my question, there is a class OA which calls the methods.

Comment: Now you need not to convert method to constructor but still assign some value to document otherwise doc.title() throw exception

Comment: The output is still giving me null.

Comment: print Value of doc.title() then check whether this value is null or not.Becuase your program is correct.

Comment: i mentioned in the question itself that if i printout the value of title in the setter method, it gives me the correct value but when in the getter method if i try to print it, im getting null.... That was the essece of my question

Comment: title=doc.title(); setTitle(title); lines does the same work.So you can remove second one. This is not sol but for clearilty.Do One thing run your prog in debug option and set debug point on both getter ans setter value and check how many how value changed after set.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you use `public void crawler() {` as constructor then just change it to `public crawler(){  }`

Comment: I've edited my question, there is a class OA which calls the methods.